# how to white List a Specific URL in Jdk 1.6?

Tags: java, sockets, java-6

Since I am getting HandShake Exception while connecting to a specific URL, I need to add the URL in JDK Security whitelist in Linux Environment.

Since this option is available for jdk1.8.

**Error**

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.getOutputStream(HTTPClientInvoker.java:1245) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:346) at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.makeInvocation(HTTPClientInvoker.java:232)`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: any way to white list a url/ip

Comment: Since you are using Java 6, it probably doesn't support modern SSL protocols, like TLS 1.2. I'm not sure "whitelisting" would solve the issue. More and more sites are dropping support for old TLS and other SSL protocols. You should upgrade your Java.

Comment: TLS 1.2+ is supported starting from  Java 1.7, so for HTTPS you have to use non JDK solution - i.e. [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

Comment: in my case update is not an option, would there be any other way?

Comment: Java 6 has not had a public update for 6 years and even paid-for support ended in December last year. Get our of there!

Comment: @RealSkeptic Is correct, AFAIK this is an error of the type "these servers couldn't even talk to each other" rather than "these servers could talk to each other but couldn't agree on a certificate". Your options are to either upgrade, or use a third party library compatible with Java 6 that supports TLS 1.2+. Java 6 has been end-of-life for over 6 years now, you should be looking to upgrade as a priority.